# How to trim html tags from text in asp.net grid view?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, tags, trim

I have used asp.net ajax html editor and i saved data in database. But now i want to retrieve it and show it in grid view. But when i retrieve that, it also shows those html tags (generated by asp.net ajax editor). So, i want to trim those tags and show plain text in grid view. How do i do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to you db and look, how it is saved. Maybe it is save encoded. If it is not the case, you can use some simple regex to remove all those tags.

```
<[^<]+?>
```

This shows you just plain text and removes all Tags

Answer (score 0):

To stripe the html tags from text you can utilize the

`RegEx.Replace("str","Pattern","replacementstring ");` method which there exist in 
System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace

for example

```
 Plain_Body = Regex.Replace(txtBody.Text, @"<[^>]*>", string.Empty);
```

here i am replacing the html specific characters with `String.Empty` or `""` you can add additional characters if you wish to pattern like @"<[^>]*>" and spaces(&nbsp) and Ampersand(&amp) etc